# How to combine 2 separate formulas based on additional criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 lines of code which both work well separately helping me to calculate staking, but I need to have both lines work in a single cell, but depending on additional criteria. For the life of me I haven't been able to get it to work
Code 1

```
=IF(F19="","",IF(F19<3.5,L18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,L18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,L18*0.004,"0"))))
```

Code 2

```
=IF(F19="","",IF(F19<3.5,$M$18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,$M$18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,$M$18*0.004,"0"))))
```

What I need to try and do is have code 1 work IF `L19>$M$18` and code 2 work IF `L<=$M$18`

I have tried many combinations of IF, AND and OR (over 2 hours so far), but can't seem to crack it. I keep getting "too many arguments" error messages

I haven't even been able to put just one side of the equation together with the required criteria

```
=IF(AND(F19="","",L19>$M$18,IF(F19<3.5,L18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,L18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,L18*0.004,"0")))))
```

If anyone can spot my obvious errors, I would appreciate your input

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include some sample data with expected results **and** your version of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the too many arguments error is probably caused because you somehow entered 4 parameters inside an "IF" function instead of 3.

If I understand your question correctly, and need to put an extra condition in each code, try:

```
=IF(AND(F19="",L19>$M$18),"",IF(F19<3.5,L18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,L18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,L18*0.004,"0"))))

=IF(AND(F19="",L19<=$M$18),"",IF(F19<3.5,$M$18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,$M$18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,$M$18*0.004,"0"))))
```

But this seems too easy to fix, I probably misunderstood your requirements.

EDIT: OK, so you need one formula for these two

```
=IF(L19>$M$18, Code1, IF(L19<=$M$18, Code2, ""))
```

Comment: Cheers, so yes to the last part of above. That is correct, one formula to incorporate Code 1 & Code 2. By the way, the 2 separate codes you did above each works fine on their own, but yes, it is having them combined which is what I am really after, but much appreciated helping me see how to have done the equation for each part helps. Excel version is 16.43 for MacOS.

Comment: did you try the formula after my edit? it should combine the two

Comment: I added the first code to where you have Code1 typed and added the second code to where Code2 is typed, but excel says there are too many arguments. It looked like this ```=IF(L19>$M$18, IF(AND(F19="",L19>$M$18),"",IF(F19<3.5,L18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,L18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,L18*0.004,"0", IF(L19<=$M$18, IF(AND(F19="",L19<=$M$18),"",IF(F19<3.5,$M$18*0.01,IF(F19<7.45,$M$18*0.006,IF(F19<11.1,$M$18*0.004,"0", ""))```

Comment: Finally got it working. When I copied each code, I stopped at the "0", missing the closing parentheses. I have now been able to get it working by correctly copying and pasting. Thanks so much for all your help. Regards

Comment: glad to hear it